# Escape blackslash in SQL query in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, escaping, backslash

I have tried this with success in **SQLite** (i.e.  only trip_id that have the character "_ S  _" are returned):

```
SELECT trip_id, arrival_time 
FROM stop_times 
WHERE stop_id  = 142444 trip_id LIKE '%\_S\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

But when I am trying to pass that query through ruby like this:

```
SELECT trip_id, arrival_time 
FROM stop_times 
WHERE stop_id  = #{arret[1].to_i} AND trip_id LIKE \'%\_S\_%\'
```

I do not have the same results (i.e. trip_id that do not have "_ S  _" are returned).

I have tried to add `Escape \'\\\'`in the ruby command with no luck.
Am I doing something wrong?

ps: I am using **Ruby 1.9.3 and SQLite 3.8.7.4** on Windows 8.

Comment: Have you tried it without escaping anything?

Comment: @popovitsj: the thing is I specifically want the characters "_S_" in the id. The underscores are not wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use backslashes with single quotes inside double quotes.

(Also, look up %q and %Q ruby operators.)

Comment: actually I was trying to escape the underscores not the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to escape underscore(_).

Try this out:

```
"SELECT trip_id, arrival_time FROM stop_times WHERE stop_id  = #{arret[1].to_i} AND trip_id LIKE '%\_S\_%'"
```

OR
If you are on **Rails**

```
StopTime.select('trip_id, arrival_time').where("stop_id = ? AND trip_id LIKE ?", arret[1].to_i, '%\_S\_%')
```

Comment: the goal is to return only this kind of trip_id "14S_S_18_4_6_54" but not this kind "14S_F1_55_7_4_55". So I need the query to search specifically for "_S_"

Comment: then the above query will do the trick. isn't it? Did you tried it?

Comment: yes I tried, but I still have the kind of trip_id I do not want (i.e the one without "_ S _")

Comment: `_` in a LIKE pattern is like `.` in a regex.

Comment: sorry for late reply had some network problem. I have update the answer.